# XSLT: extracting unique attribute values

Tags: xslt, grouping

Please help, I’m an XSLT newbie and I’m trying to transform one XML format into another.

I need to extract unique attribute values and transform the values into a new format. The example XML below shows the original and new/target format.

I've spent ages trying to do this without any enjoy.  Can anyone help out or give me some pointers?

Original format:

```
<base>
  <level>
    <level2 Name ="AA" value="1"/>
  </level>
  <level>
    <level2 Name ="BB" value="2"/>
  </level>
  <level>
    <level2 Name ="BB" value="3"/>
  </level>
  <level>
    <level2 Name ="CC" value="4"/>
  </level>
  <level>
    <level2 Name ="AA" value="5"/>
  </level>
</base>
```

New format:

```
<base>
  <levelNames>
    <level level2Name ="AA"/>
    <level level2Name ="BB"/>
    <level level2Name ="CC"/>
  </levelNames>
</base>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post what XSLT you've tried so far, and we'll make suggestions

Answer (score 11):

XSLT Soln:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="LevelDistint" match="level2" use="@Name"/>
    <xsl:template match="base">
        <base>
            <levelNames>
                <xsl:for-each select="level/level2[generate-id() = generate-id(key('LevelDistint', @Name)[1])]">
                    <level>
                        <xsl:attribute name="level2Name"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@Name)"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </level>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </levelNames>
        </base>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT O/P:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<base>
    <levelNames>
        <level level2Name="AA"/>
        <level level2Name="BB"/>
        <level level2Name="CC"/>
    </levelNames>
</base>
```

Answer (score 2):

Once again the [Muenchian grouping technique](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) appears to be the missing piece.

Fairly trivial problem for it, so I'll let you do your own work to get to grips with Muench.

Comment: I'm ambivalent between voting this up and moving on and posting a solution and feeling guilty about it. Damn you. :-D But you are probably right in suspecting that this is homework, so I refrain.

Comment: If you've done it once, you'll see how easy it really is. You just have to get the idea. For most common XSLT problems I really recommend to first have a look here: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/sect21.html

Comment: @Boldewyn - yeah that's an excellent resource for beginners, albeit unsightly :)

Comment: *sigh* anyone care to explain the downvote? Is it because I didn't do the OP's work for him?

Answer (score 0):

Please create first xsl:key then u can use below code easily.

xsl:key name="levelName" match="level2" use="@Name"

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="base">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:element name="levelNames">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="level">
        <xsl:for-each select="level2[count(.|key('levelName', @Name)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" data-type="text" select="@Name"/>
            <xsl:element name="{local-name(..)}">
                <xsl:attribute name="level2Name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```