# Extracting unique attribute values with xslt version 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I have an xml that I want to transform with XSLT version 1.0.
The (partial) input looks like this :

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <examples>
        <example>
            <firstAttribute id="first_attribute_id">
                <values>
                    <value>
                        <innerValue locale="en-US">EN_US_1_VAL</innerValue>
                        <innerValue locale="it-IT">IT_IT_1_VAL</innerValue>
                    </value>
                    <value>
                        <innerValue locale="it-IT">IT_IT_2_VAL</innerValue>
                    </value>
                    <value>
                        <innerValue locale="en-US">EN_US_2_VAL</innerValue>
                    </value>
                    <value>
                        <innerValue locale="it-IT">IT_IT_3_VAL</innerValue>
                        <innerValue locale="en-US">EN_US_3_VAL</innerValue>
                    </value>
                    <value>
                        <innerValue locale="it-IT">IT_IT_4_VAL</innerValue>
                    </value>
                </values>
            </firstAttribute>

            <extraData>
                <secondAttribute id="second_attribute_id">
                    <values>
                        <value>
                            <innerValue locale="en-US">US_1_VAL</innerValue>
                            <innerValue locale="it-IT">IT_1_VAL</innerValue>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <innerValue locale="en-US">US_2_VAL</innerValue>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <innerValue locale="it-IT">IT_2_VAL</innerValue>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <innerValue locale="en-US">US_3_VAL</innerValue>
                            <innerValue locale="it-IT">IT_3_VAL</innerValue>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <innerValue locale="it-IT">IT_4_VAL</innerValue>
                        </value>
                    </values>
                </secondAttribute>
            </extraData>
        </example>
    </examples>
</root>
```

and I want to group the locale-specific data by locale which is specified inside the locale attribute - **expected output** :

```
<root>
    <testData>
        <test-attributes>
            <test-attribute name="first_attribute_id" xml:lang="en-US">
                <value>EN_US_1_VAL</value>
                <value>EN_US_2_VAL</value>
                <value>EN_US_3_VAL</value>
            </test-attribute>
            <test-attribute name="first_attribute_id" xml:lang="it-IT">
                <value>IT_IT_1_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_IT_2_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_IT_3_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_IT_4_VAL</value>
            </test-attribute>
        </test-attributes>
    </testData>
    <testData>
        <test-attributes>
            <test-attribute name="second_attribute_id" xml:lang="en-US">
                <value>US_1_VAL</value>
                <value>US_2_VAL</value>
                <value>US_3_VAL</value>
            </test-attribute>
            <test-attribute name="second_attribute_id" xml:lang="it-IT">
                <value>IT_1_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_2_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_3_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_4_VAL</value>
            </test-attribute>
        </test-attributes>
    </testData>
</root>
```

This is the xslt file that I'm using which does not produce the desired output :

```
<xsl:stylesheet
                xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" xalan:indent-amount="2"/>    
    <xsl:key name="firstLocales" match="firstAttribute/values/value/innerValue" use="@locale"/> 
    <xsl:key name="secondLocales" match="secondAttribute/values/value/innerValue" use="@locale"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="root">
            <xsl:for-each select="root/examples/example">
                <xsl:element name="testData">
                    <xsl:element name="test-attributes">
                        <xsl:for-each select="firstAttribute">
                            <xsl:for-each select="values/value/innerValue[generate-id() = generate-id(key('firstLocales',@locale)[1])]">
                                <xsl:element name="test-attribute">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="../../../@id"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="xml:lang"><xsl:value-of select="@locale"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:variable name="CurrentLocale" select="@locale"/>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="../../../values/value/innerValue">
                                        <xsl:if test="@locale = $CurrentLocale">
                                            <xsl:element name="value">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                            </xsl:element>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>

                <xsl:if test="extraData">
                    <xsl:for-each select="extraData">
                        <xsl:element name="testData">
                            <xsl:element name="test-attributes">
                                <xsl:for-each select="secondAttribute">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="values/value/innerValue[generate-id() = generate-id(key('secondLocales',@locale)[1])]">
                                        <xsl:element name="test-attribute">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="../../../@id"/></xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="xml:lang"><xsl:value-of select="@locale"/></xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:variable name="CurrentLocale" select="@locale"/>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="../../../values/value/innerValue">
                                                <xsl:if test="@locale = $CurrentLocale">
                                                    <xsl:element name="value">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                    </xsl:element>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have stepped on the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073685/xslt-extracting-unique-attribute-values) but apparently I'm doing something wrong. The first part (where firstAttribute is used) is transformed successfully, however the second part remains empty - *current output* :

```
<root>
    <testData>
        <test-attributes>
            <test-attribute name="first_attribute_id" xml:lang="en-US">
                <value>EN_US_1_VAL</value>
                <value>EN_US_2_VAL</value>
                <value>EN_US_3_VAL</value>
            </test-attribute>
            <test-attribute name="first_attribute_id" xml:lang="it-IT">
                <value>IT_IT_1_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_IT_2_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_IT_3_VAL</value>
                <value>IT_IT_4_VAL</value>
            </test-attribute>
        </test-attributes>
    </testData>
    <testData>
        <test-attributes/>
    </testData>
</root>
```

Can you please help me with this transformation - either to fix my .xslt file or to use another approach - I have to stick to XSLT version 1.0.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I have tested your XSLT with the input XML with `xsltproc`(an XSLT-1.0 processor) and the output matches your desired output. Thus, I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @zx485 - Well, for some reason the transformation for "secondAttribute" does not work with my execution and maybe with another approach for the xslt transformation I can get both "firstAttribute" and "secondAttribute" being transformed as expected. I am not sure why it does not generate anything when the focus is on "secondAttribute".

Comment: @zx485 The body of this for-loop is never reached for some reason :
`<xsl:for-each select="values/value/innerValue[generate-id() = generate-id(key('secondLocales',@locale)[1])]">`

Comment: I don't know what you're doing. but the `<xsl:if test="extraData">                    <xsl:for-each select="extraData">` clause matches, and the rest does seem to look ok, also.